# Append with cloud-init write_files

Tags: cloud-init

When using `write_files` with cloud-init, is it possible to append content?  If so, how?

```
write_files: [
  {
    "path": "/home/user/some-file",
    "content": "\nLine to append!"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

per https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#write-files

```
write_files:
  - path: /home/user/some-file
    content: | 
       Line to append!
    append: true
```

Answer (score 19):

It was not possible, but I added the functionality and raised [a merge request](https://code.launchpad.net/~j.w.baxter/cloud-init/+git/cloud-init/+merge/359975) which was subsequently approved.

The functionality is available from 18.5 onwards.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks.  Looking forward to using the change in the future.

Comment: I think the functionality as been released already since the link says merged to master on 2018-12-06 ? It would be good if you can edit your answer as the documentation seems not up to date